# How to overwrite a jQuery touchSwipe handler?

Tags: jquery, swipe

I built a GUI for a PhoneGap app. There are a lot of swipeable pages to navigate through the app. I use the jQuery plugin "touchSwipe" to set the swipe handlers.

The amount of pages varies when I click a button that adds a new page to the app.

My problem is that swipes on new pages don't work when I add a new page. When I add a page I simply call the method again which sets the "touchSwipe" handlers.

```
$(".page").swipe({
 swipeStatus: function(event, phase,
 direction, distance, duration,fingerCount) {
  CODE HERE
 }
});
```

So The hanlder is attached to all elements with the class "page". The new elements added also have this class.

I guess it is not possible to overwrite the handler?

---

Due to performance problems I cannot add the swipe handler to single elements. I am testing around in a little example script.

```
 $("#swipeField").swipe({
        swipeStatus: function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            $(this).text("You swiped: " + direction);
        }
    });

    $("#unbindSwipeHandler").click(function() {
        $("#swipeField").unbind();
    });

    $("#setSwipeHandler").click(function() {
        $("#swipeField").swipe({
            swipeStatus: function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                $(this).text("You swiped: " + direction);
            }
        });
    });
```

I guess this solution should have a better performance. The thing is it simply won't work. As you can see when I open the page the swipe handlers get set and the direction is shown in the swipe field. After clicking the button to unbind it the text doesn't change any longer. But when I press the "setSwipeHandler" button nothing happens - the handler does not get set.

So can't I bind a previously .unbind() element?

Comment: Try and get a reference to only the new added page and then call `swipe` only on that.  E.g. `var newPage = {new page code here};  $(newpage).swipe...`

Comment: This is the current way I do it. As soon as a new page gets created I call a "setSwipe" function and pass a reference of the swipeable element with the call. But this way won't work due to the performance of the swipes is horrible after adding more than 10 pages.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem actually is now?! Is it performance or is it that adding a new page means the swipe handler doesn't work for it?

Comment: Show us the code you use to add the pages and your initial listeners too if possible.

Comment: The performance is my problem. But when I try to solve is I have another problem. I edit some things in my top post to show it to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `destroy` instead of `unbind`

```
$("#unbindSwipeHandler").click(function() {
        $("#swipeField").swipe('destroy');
    });
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! This works. But I still have performance problems. I guess I will open another question for this.

Comment: What are your problems now!?

Comment: After adding some pages the swiping transitions get pretty choppy. But I guess I know how to fix this problem. Thanks again for your help!